# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object after server move

Tags: php, pdo

I am stumped, I changed hosts and I am now getting "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" on a script that has been working for months on the old server. I have read around here and tried several things I found but nothing seems to make it work again.

I am new at this so speak slowly and clearly please. ;)

```
$dbh = connect_db(); 

    $sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM ppipn WHERE txn_id = :txn_id';
    $result = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
    $result->execute(array(':txn_id' => $txn_id)); 
    $number_of_rows = $result->fetchColumn(); 

    if ($number_of_rows>0){
    die();
    }
```

The function:

```
function connect_db()
{
    $DbHost = 'localhost';
    $DbName = '***n';
    $DbUser = '***';
    $DbPass = '***';
    $table;

    try
    {
        $connection = new PDO('mysql:host='.$DbHost.';dbname='.$DbName, $DbUser, $DbPass);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, true);
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        // Proccess error
        echo 'Cannot connect to database: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    return $connection;
}
```

Comment: Did you in fact export your DB data then imported it back in to the new server? I'm stumped.

Comment: Your connect_db function catches a connection error, but it proceeds to return $connection anyway.  Can you tell if that PDOException is being thrown?

Comment: Just for giggles, because I am perplexed why this isn't working nor throwing and exception, can you declare `$connection = null;` above the try block and see if that does anything. I'm almost positive `try/catch` doesn't limit scope, but it is worth a try.

Comment: I tested your code and added the `$txn_id` variable with a known value in DB. Voted to close as: This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.**

Comment: In order... Yes, database was exported and imported at new host and checked.

I have all error reporting on and can not see any error.

Trying $connection = null now Fingers crossed!

Please don't close this yet, if it isnt an issue with the script I am going to need to have a rough idea where to start when calling tech support and at this point I have none.

Comment: @user3154948 As per docs https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/89 - `Host name = (use the server IP address)` and you're using `localhost`. Your previous host's DB settings may have required you to use `localhost`, but Bluehost's settings doesn't seem to be the case here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that $dbh  in the line $dbh->prepare()  is not an object.

Your connect_db() function can either return a built PDO object, or echo "Cannot connect" and return a variable named $connection, that is empty.

Your connect_db() function is almost certainly unable to connect, and you aren't seeing the error echo'd out.

Comment: I was thinking the very same at first, but OP states: *"I changed hosts and I am now getting "Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object" on a script that has been working for months on the old server."* - So, that's what I don't get.

Comment: I'm thinking that the new host does not have access to connect to the DB, like a firewall block or something.

Comment: You may be right. If OP posted full code, then another factor would be `$txn_id`, I don't see it being defined anywhere. It could be a mix of everything that's been said.

Comment: the error is being thrown before txn_id is even referenced, I doubt that's the issue.

Comment: I tested OP's code as is, with the exception of adding `$txn_id` variable with a known value in DB and it worked. This similar comment has been posted under OP's question. OP might be doing an include, who knows.

Comment: Yes, this script has worked perfectly for almost 6 months on the old server/host.

I am doing an include, the function is called by a Paypal listener file. Function is in another folder.  So the file structure is 
base dir - listener.php
base dir - common/function.php

The code you see is called after verifying the sale is complete and verified in a two step process, trying echoing all variables now... 

SO CONFUSED AT THIS POINT!!

Comment: Could it be a register_globals issue?????? Although I am leaning towards a server issue myself at this point.  If anyone has any ideas what the server issue could be I would love to hear it. host is Bluehost.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Could it be a register_globals issue?????? Although I am leaning towards a server issue myself at this point. If anyone has any ideas what the server issue could be I would love to hear it. host is Bluehost." –  user3154948*

As per Bluehost's docs https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/89
`Host name = (use the server IP address)` and you're using presently `localhost`.

Your previous host's DB settings may have required you to use `localhost`, but Bluehost's settings doesn't seem to be the case here. This is normal to change from server to server/hosting services.

---

The following has been taken from their Web site: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/89

```
Configuration Settings:

Use the following configuration settings for connecting to your database

Host name = (use the server IP address)
Database name = (cpanelUsername_databaseName)
Database username = (cpanelUsername_databaseUsername)
Database password = (the password you entered for that database user)
MySQL Connection Port = 3306
TCP or UDP, either is fine.
```

Therefore, change `localhost` to the IP address they have assigned for you. Check your Email for any details that were sent to you on signing up, or [**contact Bluehost**](https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help) in order to find out what the IP address setting is that you are supposed to use.

```
$DbHost = 'localhost'; // change this
```

See also: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/2167

Comment: Per tech support localhost was correct, I never would have found that if that was the problem, but it wasn't. But it is fixed! I ?'d if the pwd was correct so created a new user, the old password was incorrect and due to an server error the new user never got associated with this database so it was failing to connect causing the non object error in BOTH instances, one which was my fault and the other a server error...But they both looked identical to the naked eye, after escalating it took 20 mins but he figured it out, so props to Bluehosts escalation dept and everyone here who tried to help!

Comment: @user3154948 That's good news, thanks for the update. I'm glad that it worked out for you. *Cheers* - I'm just wondering why they put up that info on their website, to be an IP address. Oh well, the good news is that, it's resolved.

Comment: I can't say for sure BUT when I was talking to them about avoiding downtime do to the server transfer they mentioned the same thing. *shrug* but it works as localhost(finally) and I specifically asked about it and they said localhost was fine, so I am leaving the damn thing alone...LOL

Comment: LOL! As the 'ol saying goes, "it's best leaving well enough alone". @user3154948 I'm glad for you. It can be frustrating, I've been there. All the best, cheers.